# PHP client that supports .7 Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, phpcassa

I looked into Cassandra Wrapper, but the download from a blog that claimed to update the client was missing files.  Anyone gotten PHPcassa or another client to work with .7 beta of Cassandra?

Comment: Do you have a reason to not use thrift?  The API is fairly straight forward.

Comment: I have a high-level REST API that thrift interfaces with, and would rather not re-write the thing in Java.

Answer (score 3):

The Thrift interface is actually pretty painful if you don't know what you're doing.

My answer to this question is a bit late, but it might be useful for others: I've put some time in to make phpcassa work with Cassandra 0.7 here: https://github.com/thobbs/phpcassa

Answer (score 1):

The [thrift interface](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ThriftInterface) is really easy to work with and you can generate it for many languages.

The [API is described well](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/API). Any wrapper is just going to use thrift. You will have to learn someone else's API anyway so why go through another level of abstraction ans slow down your app?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at SimpleCassie. Works with 0.7.
http://code.google.com/p/simpletools-php/wiki/SimpleCassie

Answer (score 0):

http://www.softwareprojects.com/resources/programming/t-cassandra-php-wrapper-07-1979.html

try this